# Fade In and Fade Out JavaScript function for all the content div on main page, on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm currently working on a web site and I need help for an opacity transition. My problem is, I want to put all my content divs on my main page and depending on which "section" the user want by clicking on my navigating bar (top of the page), the corresponding div will fade in while the current div will fade out.  I thought about using jQuery, but I think I prefer doing that by myself. Here's my code (which doesn't work, obviously):

```
function ShowDiv(id) {
    var activeDiv = document.getElementById(id);
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("contentDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i] != activeDiv) {
            divs[i].style.opacity = "0";
            divs[i].style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "all 1s ease-in-out");
            divs[i].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
    activeDiv.style.position = "block";
    activeDiv.style.opacity = "1";
    activeDiv.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "all 1s ease-in-out");
}
```

The function is "triggered" when I click on my navigating bar. Depending on what is clicked, the "id" will be different. Basically, I make a variable that content the "need to be shown" div, and then the others. I want the "non selected" divs to fade out, and then the "selected" div to fade in, but that doesn't work. I searched but I didn't find any answer, but one interesting thing is that the first time it will work, but won't the second, third, etc.. time.

Any suggestions? Do I really need to use jQuery?

Comment: Just curious, why are you so reluctant to use jQuery?

Comment: Can you add this to jsfiddle & share, with what you have tried.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/u2gz4/

Comment: Making my own things without using libraries make my understanding much better :)  And it makes what you post, SVS, but that's not what I want, obviously

Comment: @Krokette i understand what you want please check my fiddle again, if add display none it will never animate. I have made it using CSS, please check the fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/u2gz4/

Comment: @SVS Oh!  I see now!  But That would make the page very long.. I want to size the page with the content and "disable" the others div, that's why I put "none" on display

Comment: @Krokette Now check the fiddle i am doing that with removing & adding a class. If it works let me know.

Comment: @SVS Wow!  That's perfect!  You are amazing, it's better than I expected from my project!  Thanks a lot

Comment: @Krokette Great! happy to hear that it works for you. Posted my answer accept it if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to something I did not so long ago. (I did however go the Jquery route) So if you decide to change your mind, here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/16/) I created to answer pretty much the same question another poster had.

Don't let this scare you, but it uses:

```
$('#Hotel, #Meals').on('click', function(){
    var el = $('#'+this.id+'body');
    if ( el.is(':visible') ) return false;
    el.animate({width:'toggle'},1000)
    $('#Mealsbody, #Hotelbody').not(el).hide();
}); 
//#Hotels & #Meals being the ID of the content you want to bring in.
//At the moment it uses .animate, but you could change this to .fadeIn if you wanted to do so
```

Anyways, if you do decide to take on Jquery, you can use this as a starting point.

Good luck,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" rel="0" onClick="ShowDiv(this.rel)">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="1" onClick="ShowDiv(this.rel)">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="2" onClick="ShowDiv(this.rel)">c</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="contentDiv" id="1">1</div>
<div class="contentDiv" id="2">2</div>
<div class="contentDiv" id="3">3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contentDiv {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease
}
.remove {
    opacity: 0;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function ShowDiv(id) {
    var activeDiv = document.getElementById(id);
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("contentDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (i != id) {
            divs[i].classList.add('remove');
        }else {
           divs[i].classList.remove('remove');
        }
    }
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/u2gz4/)**